# Don't show jquery tooltip in specific cases

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-tooltip

I have a table and for one column I want to have a tooltip in each row. So all cells in one column have specific class, 'cell1' so I made tooltip with jquery:

```
$(table).uitooltip({
  items: 'cell1',
  content: 'some content'
});
```

What I want to do is to not show the tooltip in case the cell value is empty. So

```
$('.cell1').html() == ""
```

Is it possible to show jquery tooltip only in some cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this provide a function to `content` which returns the text to be shown in the tooltip. In cases where you do not want to show the tooltip at all, return `null`.

```
$(table).uitooltip({
  items: 'cell1',
  content: function() {
    return $(this).html().trim() !== '' ? 'some content' : null;
  }
});
```